# How to input numbers of a list individually from user input?

Tags: python, input, append

I need make program that asks, how many numbers I want to add list example 5, then it asks individually those numbers and last prints out list in that order. I otherwise got to work but don't know how to do that part when it asks individually those numbers.

This is what program should work.

```
How many numbers you want to add list: 5

Number 1: 76
Number 2: 9
Number 3: 32
Number 4: 77
Number 5: 3

List:
[76, 9, 32, 77, 3]
```

And here is my code:

```
amount = int(input("How many numbers do you want to add to the list? "))
numbers = []
numbers.append()
print(numbers)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

*I am using `f-strings` here. This only works in Python 3.6+.*

```
n = int(input('How many numbers do you want to add to the list? '))
lst = []
for i in range(1,n+1):
    temp = int(input(f'Number {i}: '))
    lst.append(temp)

print(f'List:\n{lst}')
```

Output:

```
How many numbers do you want to add to the list? 5

Number 1: 67
Number 2: 6
Number 3: 45
Number 4: 9
Number 5: 1

List:
[67, 6, 45, 9, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this direct assigment with list comprehension:

```py
[int(input(f'Number {i+1}: ')) for i in range(int(input('How many: ')))]
```

or a more expressive version:

```py
def numbers(amount):
    return [
        int(input(f'Number {i+1}: ')) 
        for i in range(amount)
    ]

n = numbers(input('How many: '))
print(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop using a `range` until the `amount` value

```
amount = int(input("How many numbers do you want to add to the list? "))
numbers = []
for i in range(amount):
    numbers.append(int(input(f"Number {i + 1}: ")))
print(numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
amount = int(input("How many numbers do you want to add to the list? "))
numbers = []


for index in range(amount):

    try:
        # Take the input
        inp_text = input(str(index + 1) + ":" )

        # Convert the input to int and add it to the number list 
        numbers.append(int(inp_text))

    except:
        pass

print(numbers)
```

I added a `try` because by mistake a letter could be added and then it would block everything

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension along with f-strings to minimize the code or use a regular for loop with or without f-strings.

List comprehension with f-strings:

```
amount = int(input("How many numbers do you want to add to the list? "))
numbers = [int(input(f"Number {index + 1}:")) for index in range(amount)]
print(numbers)
```

Regular for loop without f-strings:

```
amount = int(input("How many numbers do you want to add to the list? "))
numbers = []
for index in range(amount):
    num = int(input("Number " + str(index + 1) + ": "))
    numbers.append(num)
print(numbers)
```

Comment: So basically the same as what I said :)

Comment: @mama It pretty much is actually, but with a slightly different syntax I guess.